# How to unit test the right way with MochaJS in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-mocha

I am new to Unit testing with MochaJS. So, I need some help of my unit testing code that I tested my app. But, for some reason I am getting `TypeError: module is not a function` . Also, does any one know any good tutorials on unit testing or end-to-end testing? Thanks for your help.

> Here is my unit test

```
    describe('Testing AngularJS Test Suite', function(){
describe('Testing AngularJS Controller', function(){

    it('should initialize the update user in the scope', function(){

    module('Portal');

    var scope = {};
    var ctrl;

    inject(function($controller){

        ctrl = $controller('HomeController', {$scope:scope});


    });

    expect(scope.title).toBeDefine();  
    expect(scope.title).toBe('Portal');  




    });




});
});
```

Comment: you need in include `angular.mock` in your `karma.conf.js`

Comment: @harishr So, I write my tests in `testingAngularUnitSpec.conf.js` and how should I include `angular.mock`?

Comment: @harishr so, include `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-mocks.js"` ?

Comment: which runner are you using to run your tests?? you will have to include it as part of runner.... but yes the file you mentioned is correct

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am using karma. But, I want to use Mocha

Comment: then you will have to add it in `karma.conf.js`